# unknown concurrent modification exception java using Iterator and Vector

Tags: java, concurrency, iterator, concurrent-programming

i keep getting concurrent modification exception

```
String[] permsList = Constants.CUST_MKT_PERMS_FIELDS;
String hiddenFieldVector = new Vector<String>(permsList.length);
Iterator<String> itr = hiddenFieldVector.iterator();

for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){    //arrayLength is never null or 0

    ...a lot of code...
    String target = fromDatabase();     //this is never null

   while(itr.hasNext() && hiddenFieldVector.contains(target)){
    hiddenFieldVector.remove(target);
    Logger.debug("itr.next() = " + itr.next());
   }

    ...a lot of code...
}
```

any ideas why?

current solution:

```
while(itr.hasNext() && hiddenFieldVector.contains(target) && (itr.next().equals(target))){
                        itr.remove();
                        Logger.debug("itr.next() = " + itr.next());
                    }
```

Comment: i need to maintain functionality of removing a string element from the hiddenFieldVector while looping...

Comment: The Iterator doesn't appear to do anything useful. I would remove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
hiddenFieldVector.remove(target);
```

Dont call `remove` on `list` while looping. Modifying list while looping throws `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Use `iterator` and call `remove` on `iterator` instead of `list`.

Example:

```
while(itr.hasNext() && hiddenFieldVector.contains(target)){
    itr.remove();
    Logger.debug("itr.next() = " + itr.next());
   }
```

Comment: @bouncingHippo Call `itr.remove()` instead. Check the [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()).

Comment: so i cannot remove a specific element in the vector?

Comment: You can remove, but not while looping. If you use iterator, get the element and check if that is the element you want to remove, if so, then call remove() on iter.

Comment: yup i jsut did that, thansk guys!!

Comment: @Nambari i want the logic such that if the current Vector element equals to target, i want it removed from the Vector. how can i do that?

Comment: @bouncingHippo: Problem is your half code. I am following your other question also. Without full code and full stack trace, it is hard to suggest proper solution.